# Python how to open and read a remote file after SSH Tunnel

Tags: python, ssh, remote-access, ssh-tunnel

I am using SSHTunnelForwared and successfully entering a remote server with the below code:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder((ssh_host, ssh_port), ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_password=ssh_password,
        remote_bind_address=("127.0.0.1", 3306)) as tunnel:
```

I would now like to read a file into python from a path inside the server. Let's say the path is `/home/user/file.json`

If I do something like

```
with open('/home/user/file.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f)
```

The program throws an error saying:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/file.json'
```

The file is obviously not being found. What Do I need to do to locate the directory? I am working within the `ssh` block so I have access to the `tunnel` object.

Answer (score 1):

when u connect u don't know the default pwd u are in so try to access to ur path then read ur file , hope this will help you

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect("5.206.0.0", username = "root", password = "root")
command = "cd /var/www/html/ && ls"
stdin, out, err = client.exec_command(command)
print "stdout: " + out.read()
```

[image]

also fo r sql :

```
import pymysql
import paramiko
import pandas as pd
from paramiko import SSHClient
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser('~')
mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(home + pkeyfilepath)

sql_hostname = 'sql_hostname'
sql_username = 'sql_username'
sql_password = 'sql_password'
sql_main_database = 'db_name'
sql_port = 3306
ssh_host = 'ssh_hostname'
ssh_user = 'ssh_username'
ssh_port = 22
sql_ip = '1.1.1.1.1'

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_pkey=mypkey,
        remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, sql_port)) as tunnel:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=sql_username,
            passwd=sql_password, db=sql_main_database,
            port=tunnel.local_bind_port)
    query = '''SELECT VERSION();'''
    data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: SoI should replace the `SSHTunnelForwarer` with `paramiko.SSHClient`?  because I am already inside the sever with that module.

Comment: yes i suggest that , give it a try i think it will resolve ur problem

Comment: This works but I am also connecting to mysql server remotely with sshtunnelForwarder and I cannot make that work with paramiko.sshclient

Comment: i update the answer re-check it with ur problem

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was using form mysql but I want a combined way of ssh tunneling and being able to get files from remote server. Do you think I can combine the above methods? i.e. having sshclient inside a sshTunnelForwarder block?